# How to get actual real Date&Time in iOS Swift? Even when user has changed Date&Time from device setting

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, datetime, offline

I want to implement offline punch functions in my application , as of now I am using system Date&Time but user can change Date&Time from device setting so it is not reliable, that’s why I want real actual time which could not be affected by device Date&Time.

Comment: please seach about NHNetworkTime-master it may be help in your case. This demo provide you real sync time even if user change device time.

Answer (score 4):

Actually we have no access if user has enabled autoTime in settings.

You can use server Time as -

**This required Internet**

`HTTPURLResponse` gives `Date` object.

Use -

```
getTimeFromServer { (serverDate) in
   print(serverDate)
 }   

func getTimeFromServer(completionHandler:@escaping (_ getResDate: Date?) -> Void){
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        if let contentType = httpResponse!.allHeaderFields["Date"] as? String {
            //print(httpResponse)
            let dFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
            let serverTime = dFormatter.date(from: contentType)
            completionHandler(serverTime)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If the device is offline (not connected to any network), you cannot get the “real actual time”. You can only get the system’s idea of the time, and that is under user control.